# How should I use os.walk() without walking in certain subdirectories?

Tags: python

I have in a dictionary stored a list of directories in which I don't want to walk in. Using os.walk(), is there a way to stop going further down once we come to know that the directory is in the dictionary? 
For instance, if I have `dict = {"a/b/c":1}`, and I have used `os.walk("a")`, I don't want to walk in `"a/b/c"` directory.

Comment: See the duplicate on how to skip a directory and all subdirectories; you remove it from the `dirs` list. Combine the name in `dirs` with the `dir` value to create a full path, test that against your dictionary. `dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if os.path.join(dir, d) not in dictionary]` would filter any full path present in `dictionary` from the `dirs` list in such a way that `os.walk()` will skip them.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped